# Еще раз вопрос про однословные и неоднословные приложения

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

Для этого мы каждый год организуем Международный семинар по стандартизации с участием компаний-разработчиков стандартов, на котором затрагиваются и проблемы переводов стандартов.

Но, с другой стороны, права автора (организации-разработчика стандарта) должны быть соблюдены при выполнении и использовании перевода.

Как я понимаю, здесь в обоих случаях неоднословные приложения и поэтому надо ставить тире: организации — разработчика стандарта, компаний — разработчиков стандартов. В отличие от однословного приложения (организации-разработчика, компаний-разработчиков). Я правильно понимаю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...Как я понимаю, здесь в обоих случаях
> неоднословные приложения и поэтому
> надо ставить тире: организации —
> разработчика стандарта, компаний —
> разработчиков стандартов. В отличие от
> однословного приложения
> (организации-разработчика,
> компаний-разработчиков).  Я правильно
> понимаю?

ПРАВИЛЬНО.